# How can I take select data from multiple excel spreadsheets and putting it to select spot on another?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a research project with hundreds of .xlsx files that have a large amount of data but they only have four cells per sheet per .xlsx that contain data I really need. In order to make analysis easier I'm trying to put all of this important data into one table and I wanted to automate the process given there are so many files.

The way I'm looking to have this structured is like this:

AX is the file name

BX is data from sheet 1 in cell B2

CX is " in cell G2

DX is " in cell G3

EX is " in cell G7

Then F - I follow that same data but from sheet 2, and if it arises J - M from sheet 3, etc.

I was looking at VBA for a bit but that didn't look like I could have that automated which is important given there are hundreds of data sheets to be collecting from.

Is there anyway that this process can be automated? Otherwise I'll be going through by hand compiling this data which will take significantly longer which is doable but time consuming.

Comment: *I was looking at VBA for a bit but that didn't look like I could have that automated* - writing VBA code for Excel is **exactly** how you would automate this. Break down your process into steps, then study how to use VBA to accomplish each step and put the pieces together. If you get stuck on a particular issue, post a new more precise question and we can help.

Comment: **Is there anyway that this process can be automated?** - Yes. It's been covered on this site and many others over the years. Google the problem and you'll find plenty of examples that you could tweak to pick up your specific ranges.